# White space added by AngularJS after variable write in a for attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fighting with a mystical Angular feature (or bug, I don't know). I have a label and an input written by different directives so, to bind them through the id/for attributes, I pass the id value as an @ variable to the label scope. The problem is that Angular adds a white space after the variable in the for attribute so the connection doesn't work. I print the variable in the link and in the template to ensure that there are no unexpected white spaces in the variable and the result is correct (no white spaces in the variable).

Check the code.

This is the directive:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('egeo.forms')
    .directive('egeoCLabel', egeoCLabel);

egeoCLabel.$inject = ['EgeoConfig'];

function egeoCLabel(EgeoConfig) {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            for: '@',
            hasHelp: '=',
            id: '@',
            label: '@',
            isHelpShown: '=',
            required: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: EgeoConfig.getEgeoPath() + '/components/label/components.label.tpl.html'
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.toggleHelp = function() {
            scope.isHelpShown = !scope.isHelpShown;
        }         
    }
}
})();
```

This is the template:

```
<label for="{{for}}" class="egeo-c-label" ng-show="{{(label != null)}}">
{{label}}

<span class="egeo-c-label__optional-mark" data-ng-if="!required"></span>

<i class="egeo-c-icon icon-help2" data-ng-if="hasHelp" data-ng-click="toggleHelp()">
</i>
</label>
```

And the renderized result is:

```
<label for="username " class="egeo-c-label ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="true" data-label="username" data-required="true" data-is-help-shown="vm.isHelpShown" data-has-help="vm.hasHelp">
username

<!-- ngIf: !required -->

<!-- ngIf: hasHelp --><i class="egeo-c-icon icon-help2 ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasHelp" data-ng-click="toggleHelp()">
</i><!-- end ngIf: hasHelp -->
```

I don't know why, Angular adds a white space after the for attribute althought it doesn't exist in the variable value.

Comment: Can you show us the part of your controller which generates the variable `$scope.for`?

Comment: Can you include some javascript code?

Comment: There no more JS code really. I pass the variable in the directive with:     <egeo-c-label data-for="{{id}}"> and as a @ bind.

Comment: Update your question with a complete code directive, a controller, and template. Best of all, if you create jsfiddle.

Comment: Updated with the whole code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by renaming my isolate scope property. Looks like a naming collision problem.

Change your isolate scope definition to:

```js
scope: {
  myFor: '@'
}
```

Pass data to it:

```
<egeo-c-label data-my-for="{{id}}">
```

Use it in your directive:

```html
<label for="{{myFor}}">
```

Comment: Yes, it seems a problem using some keywords. Thanks